# How to change font size of all .docx document with python-docx

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

So, Im trying to solve problem with Python Docx. I need to refactor my .docx document, I need to change Font Name and Font Size of all document. What solutions can you suggest?

With this code Font Name are changing, but Font Size are not.

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
document = Document('path/to/file.docx')


style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Arial'
font.size = Pt(10)
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    paragraph.style = document.styles['Normal']
document.save('refactored.docx')
```

Comment: I get the error:    fontA.size = Pt(10)
NameError: name 'Pt' is not defined! why please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to iterate over runs for font changes.

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    paragraph.style = document.styles['Normal']
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.size = Pt(10)
```

Comment: That's working! Thanks a lot! I cant upvote that ur answer is usefull, because i have less than 15 reputation...

Comment: your welcome,you can just accept the answer. no need for upvote.

Comment: Not changing my font! Do you know why, please? styleQ = docA.styles['Normal']
fontQ = styleQ.font
fontQ.name = 'Arial'

for paragraph in docQ.paragraphs:
    paragraph.style = styleQ #docQ.styles['Normal']
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.name = 'Arial'
        run.font.size = Pt(12)