# How to change style of hyperlinks in existing document, especially font size and name

Tags: python-docx

I would like to stick with python-docx library. But if there are other ways would love to hear them.

Currently i'm using this snippet for changing style in document, but links are no affected. Should I recreate them?

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

document = Document("existing file.docx")

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    # paragraph.style = document.styles['Normal']
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.name = 'Arial'
        run.font.size = Pt(10)
```

Snippet is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57537365/14871998).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from docx.oxml.shared import qn
```

This function is copy-paste from [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/85#issuecomment-1010150776). Because paragraph.runs is not returning Run instances for hyperlinks childrens.

```py
def getParagraphRuns(paragraph):
    def _get(node, parent):
        for child in node:
            if child.tag == qn('w:r'):
                yield Run(child, parent)
            if child.tag == qn('w:hyperlink'):
                yield from _get(child, parent)
    return list(_get(paragraph._element, paragraph))
```

If you want to get sequence of Run instances only for hyperlinks use this function instead.

```py
def getHyperlinksRuns(paragraph):
    def _get(node, parent):
        for child in node:
            if child.tag == qn('w:hyperlink'):
                yield from returnRun(child, parent)
    def returnRun(node, parent):
        for child in node:
            if child.tag == qn('w:r'):
                yield Run(child, parent)
    return list(_get(paragraph._element, paragraph))
```

and voila

```py
for p in document.paragraphs:
    runs = getParagraphRuns(p) 
    # runs = getHyperlinksRuns(p)
    for run in runs:
        run.font.name = 'Arial'
        run.font.size = Pt(10)
```